Встроить параметры в атрибут src в разметке
Есть разметка виджета, в котором div и один или несколько тегов script. Нужно встроить строку с параметрами param1=value1&param2=value2... в те теги script, в которых присутствует атрибут src. Причем, адрес в src может содержать как https://, так и http:// или //. Параметры в src могут присутствовать или отсутствовать.
Хотел сделать через регулярные выражения, вот мой вариант:
/<scripts+([^>]*src=["']?)([^"'>]+)(["'][^>]*?)>/i

Но такое выражение не работает. Помогите исправить, либо, может быть, придёт идея, как сделать проще.

<?php
$html = '<html><head><script src="/path/to/script.js"></script></head><body><div>'.
        '<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.3.0/lodash.js"></script>'.
        '<script src="http://test.com/scripts/test.js?123456789"></script>'.
        '<script src="https://roga-and-kopyta.ru/scripts/pl.js?"></script>'.
        '<script src="//scripts/magic.js?isset=true"></script>'.
        '</div></body></html>';
//Находим все <script> внутри <div> (чтобы отсеять те что в <head>)
preg_match_all('/(<div>.*?(<script.*?><\/script>).*?<\/div>)/imu', $html, $matches);
if ( is_array( $matches ) && count( $matches ) > 1 && is_array( $matches[1] ) && count( $matches[1] ) > 0 ) {
    //Теперь у всех найденных <script> получаем src="..."
    preg_match_all('/<\s*script[^>]+src\s*=\s*[\'"]\s?(.*?)*([^\'" ]+)\s*["\'][^>]*><\/script>/imu', $matches[1][0], $matches);
    if ( is_array( $matches ) && count( $matches ) > 2 && is_array( $matches[2] ) && count( $matches[2] ) > 0 ) {
        //в цикле перебираем все src
        for( $i = 0; $i < count( $matches[2] ); $i++ ) {
            $src = $matches[2][$i];
            //Если в src есть ? значит могут быть параметры 
            $tmp = explode('?', $src, 2);
            //Расписано для понимая, все это можно заменить тернарным оператором
            if ( count($tmp) > 1 ) {
                if (  trim( $tmp[1] ) != '' ) {
                    //И символ "?" есть и параметры после него есть, добавляем свои
                    $src .= "&param1=value&param2=value2";
                } else {
                    //Символ "?" есть, а параметров после него нет, добавляем свои
                    $src .= "param1=value&param2=value2";
                }
            } else {
                //Увы, "?" нет, добавляем свои параметры
                $src .= "?param1=value&param2=value2";
            }
            //Теперь меняем src внутри script
            $script = $matches[0][$i];//preg_replace("/\//", "\/", $matches[2][$i])
            $script = preg_replace("/".preg_quote($matches[2][$i], "/")."/imu", $src, $script);
            //Меняем <script> внутри html
            $html = preg_replace("/".preg_quote($matches[0][$i], "/")."/imu", $script, $html);
        }
    }
}

Результат
<html><head><script src="/path/to/script.js"></script></head><body><div><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.3.0/lodash.js?param1=value&param2=value2"></script><script src="http://test.com/scripts/test.js?123456789&param1=value&param2=value2"></script><script src="https://roga-and-kopyta.ru/scripts/pl.js?param1=value&param2=value2"></script><script src="//scripts/magic.js?isset=true&param1=value&param2=value2"></script></div></body></html>


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
